# How to put a variable into getElementById.style.backgroundImage

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

The URL is stored in an Array. I want to use it to change the div background image. But it didn't work.
e.g.

```
<div id = "test"></div>
let arr = [1,2,3,'https://reurl.cc/RX3bkD'];
document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundImage = "url(arr[3])";
```

What could I do? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @dandavis — The `url()` part is a **vital** bit of CSS syntax

Comment: @Quentin: fair nuff, good call, though I swore it _used_ to work fine w/o `url()`...

Answer (score 0):

you are inserting a string into the url instead of the value:

try using the template literal syntax ( https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals ):

```
 document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundImage = `url(${arr[3]})`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use quotes to append strings and variables together:

```
document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + arr[3] + ")";
```

Or you can use a template (note the back ticks are needed) instead of quotes.

```
document.getElementById("test").style.backgroundImage = `url(${arr[3]})`;
```